# Click see more till the end using selenium python

Tags: python, selenium

I need to extract the articles from this link http://www.biography.com/people

so I am using selenium with python to press "see more" until download all the people piography so this is my code

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
chrome_path = r"./chromedriver"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_path)
driver.get("http://www.biography.com/people")
while(True):
    try:
        element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[contains(@class, 'm-component-footer--loader') and contains(@class, 'm-button')]")))
        element.click()
    except TimeoutException:        
        break
```

but the problem this code working sometimes and hust for one time. and after that give me this exception.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sel.py", line 17, in <module>
    element.click()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 77, in click
    self._execute(Command.CLICK_ELEMENT)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 493, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 252, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 194, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Element <button class="m-component-footer--loader m-button" ng-show="properties.collection.hasMoreItems || loading" ng-click="buttonPressed()" phx-track-event="" phx-track-id="load more" ng-class="{'is-inverted': properties.background.inverted}" tabindex="0" aria-hidden="false">...</button> is not clickable at point (459, 883). Other element would receive the click: <div class="kskdDiv" style="position: fixed; overflow: hidden; height: 90px !important; z-index: 2000000; width: 728px !important;-webkit-transform-origin:0 100%;-moz-transform-origin:0 100%;-ms-transform-origin:0 100%;-o-transform-origin:0 100%;transform-origin:0 100%;left:50%;bottom:0px;-webkit-transform:scale(1) translateX(-50%);-moz-transform:scale(1) translateX(-50%);-ms-transform:scale(1) translateX(-50%);-o-transform:scale(1) translateX(-50%);transform:scale(1) translateX(-50%)" data-kiosked-role="boundary">...</div>
  (Session info: chrome=58.0.3029.81)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.29.461571 (8a88bbe0775e2a23afda0ceaf2ef7ee74e822cc5),platform=Linux 4.8.0-49-generic x86_64)
```

Edit 1:
When I change the time wait from 20 to 9999999999999. it is download 4 pages and after that throw the same error.

Comment: Why can't you try Web scraping? more details : http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/python-on-the-web/web-scraping-with-beautifulsoup

Answer (score 1):

I prefer using css selectors

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

chrome_path = r"./chromedriver"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_path)
driver.get("http://www.biography.com/people")
click_more = True
while click_more:
    time.sleep(1)
    element = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('button.m-component-footer--loader')
    if element:
        element.click()
    else:
        click_more = False
```

Comment: Is it working with you? because I tried your code. and it throw exception after the second page.

Comment: By second page you mean after 1 click? Yes it works for me.. only difference is I used the Firefox driver. What's the exception.. maybe increase the sleep time.

Answer (score 0):

It work for me 
the point is the load should disappear then click the button....
    customdriver.waitForElementInvisible(loading_loc)
    customdriver.clickElementsBySendKey(button,"\n")

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoAlertPresentException
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select


class SeleniumBaseClass(object):
    def __init__(self,driver):
        self.driver = driver
    def open(self,URL):
        self.driver.get(URL)
    def driverURLChange(self,URL):  
        print("change URL" + URL)
        self.driver.get(URL)
    def currentUrl(self):
        print("URL   " +  self.driver.current_url)
        return self.driver.current_url

    def locateElement(self, loc):
        try:
            print(loc)
            element = WebDriverWait(self.driver,10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located(loc))
            return element
        except:
            print ("cannot find {0} element".format(loc))
        return None

    def waitForElementInvisible(self,loc):
        #load-spinner
        try:
            element = WebDriverWait(self.driver,10).until(EC.invisibility_of_element_located(loc))
            return True
        except:
            print ("cannot invisibility_of_element {0} element".format(loc))
        return False            

    def send_key_with_Element(self,loc,value):
        self.locateElement(loc).clear()
        self.locateElement(loc).send_keys(value)
    def click_with_Element(self,loc):
        self.locateElement(loc).click()
    def clickElementsBySendKey(self,loc,value):
        self.locateElement(loc).send_keys(value)  




customdriver = SeleniumBaseClass(webdriver.Chrome())

customdriver.open("http://www.biography.com/people")
button = (By.XPATH,"//button[contains(@class, 'm-component-footer--loader')]")
loading_loc = (By.XPATH,"//div[@aria-hidden='true' and @translate='FEED_LOADING']")

while True:
    customdriver.waitForElementInvisible(loading_loc)
    customdriver.clickElementsBySendKey(button,"\n")
```

Answer (score 0):

you should check for seemore availability on the screen ..
from selenium import webdriver
import time

```
chrome_path = r"./chromedriver"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_path)
driver.get("http://www.biography.com/people")
click_more = True
while click_more:
    time.sleep(1)
    element = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('button.m-component- 
        footer--loader')
    if element.is_displayed():
        element.click()
    else:
        click_more = False
```